# 5 barplot через функцию (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Занимаюсь анализом данных(только учусь), скачал датасет для тренировки, пытался обернуть в функцию построения графиков, вот так:

```
month_trend_2018 = month_trend.query('year == 2018').groupby('month').agg({'dead':'sum', 'injured':'sum', 'total':'sum'}).reset_index()

def bar_tables(data, x_col, y_col):
    ax=data.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, kind='bar', figsize=(25, 7), rot=360, grid=False)
    for p in ax.patches:
        height = p.get_height()
        ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2,
        height + 50,
        '{:.0f}'.format(height),
        fontsize = 13,
        ha='center')
    plt.legend(['Dead', 'Injured', 'Total'])
    plt.title('Динамика по годам', size=16)
    plt.xlabel('Год', size=14)
    plt.ylabel('Жертвы, чел.', size=14)
    plt.show()

bar_tables(month_trend_2018, month_trend_2018['month'], month_trend_2018[['dead', 'injured', 'total']])
```

Таблица выглядит так:

|  | month | dead | injured | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 23 | 89 | 112 |
| 1 | 2 | 43 | 64 | 107 |
| 2 | 3 | 15 | 68 | 83 |

В итоге ошибка:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>  c:\Users\pavel\Documents\Saves
> repository\saves\history_analysis.ipynb Ячейка 26 in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 bar_tables(month_trend_2018, month_trend_2018['month'], month_trend_2018[['dead', 'injured', 'total']])
>
> c:\Users\pavel\Documents\Saves repository\saves\history_analysis.ipynb
> Ячейка 26 in bar_tables(data, x_col, y_col)
> 1 def bar_tables(data, x_col, y_col):
> ----> 2   ax=data.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, kind='bar', figsize=(25, 7), rot=360, grid=False)
> 3   for p in ax.patches:
> 4       height = p.get_height()
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\plotting_core.py:937,
> in PlotAccessor.**call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 935 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
> 936     x = data_cols[x]
> --> 937 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
> 938     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
> 939 data = data.set_index(x)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3511,
> in DataFrame.**getitem**(self, key)
>     3509     if is_iterator(key):
> 3510         key = list(key)
> -> 3511     indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
>     3513 # take() does not accept boolean indexers   
> 3514 if getattr(indexer, "dtype", None) == bool:
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5782,
> in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)  
>   5779 else:
> 5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer =
> self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
> -> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
>     5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
>     5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
>    >5786 # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:
> 5842,
> in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name) 
>    5840
> if use_interval_msg: 
>    5841         key = list(key)
> -> 5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]") 
>    5844 not_found =
> list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())  
>   5845
> raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
>
> KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
> 12], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

В таблице все колонки интовые, если это важно, то работаю в VSCode версия Python 3.10.4
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим, в процессе гугления не смог найти описания подобных проблем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вставьте ваш код https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5860/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: И первые несколько строк month_trend_2018

Comment: В какой строке ошибка то? Зачем вы обрезаете вывод об ошибке, показывайте его целиком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bar_tables(data, x_col, y_col):
    ax=data.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, kind='bar', figsize=(25, 7), rot=360, grid=False)
...
bar_tables(month_trend_2018, month_trend_2018['month'], month_trend_2018[['dead', 'injured', 'total']])
```

Фактически вы делаете что-то такое:

```
df.plot(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])
```

А нужно указывать в качестве `x` и `y` названия колонок, а не сами данные:

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y')
```

Возвращаясь к вашему коду. Соответственно, нужно вызывать функцию, передавая не данные, а названия колонок. Насколько я понимаю, так:

```
bar_tables(month_trend_2018, 'month', ['dead', 'injured', 'total'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, в пандас есть метод для гистограмм `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`, первая картинка совмещает все столбцы на одном рисунке, вторая делит картинку по столбцам:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

month = [1, 2, 3]
dead = [23, 4, 15]
injured = [89, 64, 68]
total = [112, 109, 83]
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': month, 'dead': dead, 'injured': injured, 'total': total})
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()

axes = df.plot.bar(rot=0, subplots=True)
axes[1].legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```